# How to update a modal DOM object after method call with JS on Rails 5.2?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to achieve something that sounds simple, but that fails in this particular context.

A Task instance is displayed in a modal window. The modal Show view includes a form which, when submitted, triggers the **verify** method in the tasks_controller. The method updates a field, and the change should be reflected in the current Show view.

Unfortunately, Rails raises an **UnknownFormat** error, claiming for a html template.

I also tried to render the javaScript snippet directly inside the method with: `render js: "document.getElementById('task-git-hash').value = ('#{ @task.git_hash }');"`  but the code is rendered literally as new html page, instead of being executed in the current view.

**show.html.erb** modal view (extract)

```
  <%= form_with model: @task, url: :verify_task, method: :post, html: {id: "verify_form"}, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="row mat-form-row">
      <div class="mat-form-field col-md-4">
        <label for="task-git-hash" class="mat-form-field-label">
          <%= t('tasks.show.GitHash') %>
        </label>
        <input id="task-git-hash" class="mat-input-element" readonly
          value="<%= @task.git_hash %>" />
      </div>
        <div class="mat-form-field col-md-6">
          <%= f.label :verify_on_technology_id, t('tasks.show.Technology'), class: "mat-form-field-label" %>
          <%= f.grouped_collection_select :verify_on_technology_id,
              values_options_for('Technologies', 1, @task.technology_id), # group
              :subs,                                 # descendants
              :code,                                 # group label
              :id, :code,                            # option key & label
              {:include_blank => false},
              { class: "mat-input-element select2-candidate" } %>
        </div>
        <div class="mat-form-field col-md-2">
          <%= f.label :git_hash, t('tasks.show.GetHash'), class: "mat-form-field-label" %>
          <button class="mat-flat-button mat-button-base mat-primary">
            <%= t('Verfiy') %>
          </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

**tasks_controller** method

```
  def verify
    ### Retrieved by Callback function
    @task.update_attribute(:git_hash, Time.now.strftime("Tested at %H:%M"))
  end
```

**verify.js.erb** view

```
document.getElementById("task-git-hash").value = ("<%= @task.git_hash %>");
```

How can I manage to update this field in the current view when the form is validated?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what part is causing problems. Are there any errors?

Comment: Yes, as the code is listed, it raises an UnknownFormat error.

Comment: The most likely reasion why this is happening is some sort of javascript error which is preventing Rails UJS from working properly. So instead of sending an asyncronous request you're just posting the form like normal. You can verify this by looking at the Rails logs and looking at what format its treating the request as. You can also use the console in your browser to inspect the page for errors and the network tab to to see what requests are actually being sent by the browser. `request.xhr?` will also tell you in Rails if it was an XHR request.

Comment: `("j (<%= @task.git_hash %>)")` also does not do what you think it does. You want `<%= j @task.git_hash %>`. Its unclear why you think that you need to use escaping here though as its just a simple string.

Comment: Yes, you are right, escaping is not needed here. Regarding the requests, the HTML status is 406 (not acceptable), and request.formats: ["text/html"] as stated in the error message. request.xhr? returns nil. Is something missing in the form declaration to consider it as asynchronous?